# Fan dimmer using MOC3021 and TRIAC suddenly stopped working. Cannot find possible reason. The circuit worked fine for two days

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, dimmer

I am trying to control speed of a fan using MOC3021, BT136 and zero crossing detector. The circuit worked fine for 2 days and then suddenly stopped working. I am unable to find the problem in the circuit. Can somebody help where could be the problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzUnku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *I am unable to find the problem* Have you tested all the parts? Something got damaged. You got to figure out what, then edit this question and add the missing information from your troubleshooting. Once you tell us what broke, we can try and figure out why it broke.

Comment: When drawing schematics, don't just draw blocks. Instead, for simple components like relays, optocouplers etc., draw a block with the internal elements shown. That way anyone can look at the schematic and tell what's going on. Triacs have symbols - don't just draw a box with three junctions on it. I've re-drawn the schematic for you. In the future, that should help you communicate better, I hope.

Comment: Aditi, why did you select the MOC3021 instead of the MOC3061?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I replaced moc3021, problem still persists. Resistors and capacitor of snubber is not burnt. Triac is damaged. I can't find the reason of how it got damaged.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I will take care of the schematics next time. Thank you :-)

Comment: @periblepsis I got the diagram from internet, researched over it and this was satisfying the requirement. Don't know about moc3061.

Comment: @AditiK Also, what have you tested in the failed unit? Those low-valued resistors worry me. I worry about whether or not they are pulse-rated and if they are sufficiently rated for the voltage you are dealing with and the dissipation that may be required of them (in pulses, which is why the pulse-rating question.) And I worry about the exact load. But bottom line, you need to look at each part and tell us which of them has changed. (I'm assuming if you built a new unit from new parts it would function.. for a while.) The MOC3061/3 has a zero-cross built in. Simple, robust, easy to use.

Comment: @AditiK Please consider pulling it apart to test each component, separately. Something isn't working as before. Find out which one or two of them aren't the same as they should be. For the capacitor, just replace it unless you happen to have an old-style capacitor checker that supports high voltage (most do not, these days, sad to say. And the old Heathkit ones that used 600 VDC for checking are... hard to find now.) I'm also wondering about leakage paths, right now. And again those low resistor values (R2/R3) are... worrying. But just shooting from hip, right now.

Comment: @periblepsis Triac is damaged. I tried several values of R2 and R3 (100 Ohm to 3.3KOhm) every possible value but it burnt instantly. This was the value that worked fine for my circuit. My load is 65 Watt wall fan. One thing, in schematic R3 is connected to MT1 and capacitor to MT2 but in my case, R3 is connected to MT2 and cap to MT1.

Comment: Post oscillograms.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the gate of triac have been damaged, as the limit value of peak gate current is 2 A. In your circuit, with a 50 % of phase angle firing, and power supply of 120 VAC, current peak will be about 3 A (see simulation, gate current in green colour). In case of 230 VAC grid, it will be higher.
[image]
I suggest to increase R2 to 180 Ohm in case power supply 120 V, and 360 Ohm for 230 VAC, as shown in typical application of MOC3021 datasheet.

Comment: I will replace. Thank you.

Comment: @Aditi: to be sure, you can test the triac with a resistive load (bulb) connecting the gate to a battery through a limiting resistor to switch on. The current for the gate should be about 80 mA, and the voltage drop of the gate is about 1 V. For example, a 9 V batery and around 100 Ohm resistor. Remember this battery will be at grid voltage, take care.